# Changed from RAID to AHCI, ubuntu installer still does not recognize SSD, Dell XPS 13

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, windows-10, raid, xps

I have been struggling for the last few days trying to install an ubuntu dual boot alongside windows 10 Education. I am on a Dell XPS 13. I have followed all the step-by-steps I can find. I have disabled hibernate, disabled my pagefile, disabled secure boot, disabled FastBoot. I have switched from RAID to AHCI. I have shrunk my C: drive to create unallocated space on which to load ubuntu.

Even now, I try to install ubuntu 19.04 through a USB and ubuntu is not seeing my SSD. The problem is when I get to what should be the Installation Type screen where it asks if you want to run side-by-side or "Something Else". It bypasses this screen and jumps to what looks like the screen I would get had I actually had the opportunity to select "Something Else". At this point, the only drive it sees is my USB drive. It does not detect the main SSD.

Please help! I have been scouring AskUbuntu and found similar questions and none of them have answers. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

ok apparently the solution is that it only works if you select the option to "Install ubuntu" from the startup screen rather than "Try ubuntu wihout installing".

Comment: No, it can't be that.